# System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open

Tags: .net-core

I`m trying  use this factory:

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory : ISqlConnectionFactory, IDisposable
        {
            private readonly string _connectionString;
            private IDbConnection _connection;

            public SqlConnectionFactory(string connectionString)
            {
                this._connectionString = connectionString;
            }

            public IDbConnection GetOpenConnection()
            {
                if (this._connection == null || this._connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    //this._connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                    this._connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString);
                    this._connection.Open();
                }

                return this._connection;
            }

            public IDbConnection CreateNewConnection()
            {
                var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                return connection;
            }

            public string GetConnectionString()
            {
                return _connectionString;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (this._connection != null && this._connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    this._connection.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

But, after some time after successful work, I get an error

System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is **open**.

What does this mean ? My connection state is **open**.

UPD. Usage example :

```
internal class GetMemberQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetMemberQuery, MemberDto>
    {
        private readonly ISqlConnectionFactory _sqlConnectionFactory;

        public GetMemberQueryHandler(ISqlConnectionFactory sqlConnectionFactory)
        {
            _sqlConnectionFactory = sqlConnectionFactory;
        }

        public async Task<MemberDto> Handle(GetMemberQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var connection = _sqlConnectionFactory.GetOpenConnection();

            var sql = "some sql";

            return await connection.QuerySingleAsync<MemberDto>(sql, new { query.MemberId });
        }
    }
```

Comment: we can't see the code that calls `ExecuteNonQuery`, so we can't see which of those many mechanisms it is using to get the connection, but: is any other code calling `Close()`? perhaps on a connection that is shared are reused? btw; you should `Dispose()` the connection in `Dispose()` *regardless* of the connection-state - simply `_connection?.Dispose();`

Comment: at the implementation level, I am a little worried about a "connection factory" that gives everyone the same connection; that sounds like a concurrency problem waiting to happen, to be honest

Comment: I`,ve added usage sample

Comment: ok; now - that individual example looks fine (Dapper won't close a connection unless it opens it), so: what I *suspect* is happening is that you are sharing that factory with multiple call-sites, which has two different problems: 1) connections are *not* thread-safe; they're intended to only have one active caller, and one active operation (with a caveat around "MARS", but that's a different topic), and 2) there's a good chance that at least one of those call sites is disposing either the connection itself, or the factory - either of which would break the shared connection for *all* usages

Comment: so: turning that around: what is lifetime/scoping of the `ISqlConnectionFactory sqlConnectionFactory` that you're passing in?